# ionic cordova run android - Ionic 4 command stuck

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

In ionic 4 - after running command 
**ionic cordova run android**

The output stuck.. the output of program is as below[image]

I am still facing issue..

My ionic info is--

**Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16

 (C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)

   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.1.1

   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.26

   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.26

   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.26

   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)

   Cordova Platforms : android 6.3.0

   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 4 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.11.0

   native-run  : 1.0.0

System:

   NodeJS : v10.15.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)

   npm    : 6.4.1

   OS     : Windows 10**

I used **ionic cordova run android --verbose**  still no success...